# Buscar datos en un ArrayList de objetos

Tags: java

Estoy creando una aplicación donde cada usuario tiene su respectivo perfil. Estos perfiles se almacenan en un `ArrayList`. Tengo problemas a la hora de crear un método para buscar usuarios registrados o presentes en el `ArrayList` y tengo que hacerlo con 2 parametros `Nombre` y `Apellido`.

Tengo la siguiente clase:

```
import java.util.*;

public class Profilo {

    static String Nombre;
    static String Apellido;
    String Intereses;
    boolean visible;

    //contructor   
    public Profilo(String nombre, String apellido,String intereses,
            boolean visibilidad) {  
        this.Nombre= nombre;
        this.Apellido= apellido;
        this.Intereses= intereses;
        this.visible = visibilidad;

    }                  
    public String getNombre() {  
        return this.Nome;
    }            
    public String getApellido() {
        return this.Cognome;
    }
```

Y otra clase que contendra los metodos para hacer login,registrarse y buscar usuarios:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;


public class PerfilManager {

    static ArrayList<Profilo> Users = new ArrayList();
    static Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);


     public static void Login() {
         //codigo
     }

     public static void Registrarse() {
        //codigo
     }

     public static void InizializaDati(){
         String nombre;
         String apellido;
         String intereses;
         boolean visibile;

         System.out.println("nombre:");
         nombre= sc.next();

         System.out.println("apellido:");
         apellido = sc.next();

         System.out.println("intereses:");
         intereses= sc.next();

         System.out.println("visible?(true/false)");  
         visibile = sc.nextBoolean();

         Perfil perfil= new Perfil(nombre,apellido,intereses,visibile);

         Users.add(perfil);
         System.out.println("peril creado!");

         ShowPerfil();
    }   

    public static void BuscaPerfil(String nome , String cognome) {
        for(int i = 0 ; i < Users.size();i++) {
            if(Users.get(i).visibile != false) {
                //muestra perfil
            } else {
                System.out.println("Este perfil es privado");    
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Por lo que veo en tu código, la lista se carga por entrada. Que hay de la base de datos? No se carga tu `ArrayList` desde la base de datos?

Comment: Creo que no está utilizando ningun enlace de datos, me refiero, está haciendo una prueba con una clase de usuarios y almacenandola en tiempo de ejecución.

Comment: si , bueno no fui muy claro , la idea es cargar los datos por input, con un scanner , y salvarlos en el ArrayList , Osea cada usuario crea su perfil y lo salva en el ArrayList y los datos de cada perfil los salvo en un File CSV .

Comment: Por favor solo menciona o utiliza el concepto "base de datos" cuando realmente trabajes con un motor de base de datos (relacional o no relacional).

Comment: Creo que tienes un problema con los `String` `Nombre` y `Apellido`, _(creo que static funciona igual en java)_, y es que estos estaran disponibles sin una instancia de `Perfil`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

La mejor manera de buscar en una lista `List` es iterando sus elementos y realizando la búsqueda:

```
public static Profilo BuscaPerfil(String nome , String cognome) {
    Profilo resultado = null;
    for (Profilo profilo : Users) {
        if (profilo.isVisible() //esta condición estaba previamente
            && profilo.getNombre().equals(nome)
            && profilo.getApellido().equals(cognome)) {
            resultado = profilo;
            break;
        }
    }
    return resultado;
}
```

El método lo he cambiado para que devuelva un `Profilo`. De esta manera, el cliente del método, es decir, el lugar donde se utiliza el método, puede realizar la acción concreta con el resultado del método. La acción puede ser: mostrar los datos del objeto en pantalla, utilizarlo para un proceso masivo de actualización de datos, utilizar el objeto para que sea parte de otro objeto, etc.

Desde Java 8, el método de búsqueda se puede reducir a lo siguiente:

```
public static Profilo BuscaPerfil(String nome , String cognome) {
    Optional<Profilo> profilo = Users.stream()
        .filter(p -> p.isVisible()
            && p.getNombre().equals(nome)
            && p.getApellido().equals(cognome))
        .findFirst();
    return profilo.isPresent() ? profilo.get() : null;
}
```

---

Consejos para mejorar tu código actual (no es parte del problema principal expuesto en la pregunta).

En Java, los miembros (atributos y métodos) estáticos pertenecen a la clase y no a las instancias de la clase (objetos). Si declaras un atributo como estático, puesto que el atributo le pertenece a la clase y no al objeto, entonces al asignar un valor a dicho atributo, este valor será compartido por todas las instancias de la clase. Por ello, en tu clase `Profilo`, los campos no deben ser estáticos. Adicional a esto, todos los campos deberían tener al menos su método getter.

La clase `Profilo` debería quedar así:

```
public class Profilo {
    private String nombre;
    private String apellido;
    private String intereses;
    private boolean visible;

    //contructor   
    public Profilo(String nombre, String apellido,String intereses,
            boolean visibilidad) {  
        this.nombre= nombre;
        this.apellido= apellido;
        this.intereses= intereses;
        this.visible = visibilidad;

    }                  
    public String getNombre() {  
        return nombre;
    }            
    public String getApellido() {
        return apellido;
    }
    private String getIntereses() {
        return intereses;
    }
    private boolean isVisible() {
        return visible;
    }
}
```

Comment: Los comentarios no deben usarse para discusiones extendidas; esta conversación ha sido [trasladada a un chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/39559/discussion-on-answer-by-luiggi-mendoza-buscar-datos-en-un-arraylist-de-objetos).

Answer (score 1):

Como `Users` es un `ArrayList` de objetos `profilo` puedes obtener de esta manera los valores:

```
   public static void BuscaPerfil(String nome , String cognome) {
      for (Profilo profilo : Users) {
            if (profilo.getNombre().equals(nome)
                && profilo.getApellido().equals(cognome)) {
                 System.out.println("Este perfil existe: " + profilo.getNombre());    
            }else{
                System.out.println("Este perfil es privado");   
           } 
        }
    }
```